# "More than" or "above"

Tags: prepositions

Which one is more accurate?

> The hormone level is **above** 10 ng/dl.

Or

> The hormone level is **more than** 10 ng/dl.

Comment: Neither is a particularly 'accurate' value.

Comment: By 'accurate,' do you mean 'idiomatic'?

Comment: @Heartspring  Yes !

Comment: I mean which one is more scientifically acceptable ?!

Comment: They're both fine.

Comment: The version with "above" more strongly implies that 10 ng/dl is an important or interesting threshold.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They both are correct.  You also could say,

> The hormone level exceeds 10 ng/dl.